# Need to print the statement inside for loop only once - Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

SO in my template i need to print a statement only once inside the for loop even it iterates many times. my code is :

```
{% for interview in scheduledinterviews %}
    {% if interview.slot.start.date == today.date %}
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-12 profile-dash">
          <h4>Today's Interviews</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to Print Todays Interview only once as it satisfies the if condition inside the loop. What Should i do?

Comment: what are you trying to do ? are you trying to check if scheduledinterviews is not empty ?? you can do like {% if scheduledinterviews %) Today Interviews{%endif%}

Comment: if you want to run your for loop only once you can use slice! like {% interview in scheduledinterviews|slice:"1" %}

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`ifchanged`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged) tag.

```
{% ifchanged interview.slot.start.date %}<h4>Today's Interviews</h4>{% endifchanged %}
```

Comment: {% ifchanged %} works under single loop but i am trying this inside two loops and it does not work. For example- 
{% for i in j %} 
   {% for k in j %}
{% ifchanged %} 
 //something here//
{% endifchanged %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

but in this case it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to disappoint you but there is no break tag in django template. For me the easiest way to go is to prepare your context data better in the respective view prior to rendering the data.